# « Des autres » ou « d'autres » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, articles

Quand est-ce qu'on doit utiliser « des autres » et quand « d'autres » ? Quelle est la différence ?

J'ai trouvé cette phrase dans mon livre de français: « vous avez d'autres appartements ? ». Est-ce qu'on peut écrire « des autres » ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il faut se demander ce que l’on dirait si l’on ne contractait pas les articles et prépositions.

Si l’on veut exprimer “de les autres”, où *de* est une préposition, *les* est l’article défini pluriel, *autres* peut être soit un substantif, soit un adjectif, on contracte “des autres”. Dans ce cas, l’on sait à quels autres l’on se réfère puisque l’on utilise l’article défini.

Si l’on veut dire “des autres”, où *des* est l’article indéfini pluriel, on contracte en “d’autres”.

Si l’on veut dire “de des autres”, où *de* est une préposition et *des* l’article indéfini, on contracte à nouveau en “d’autres”.

> J’ai fait le tour des autres boucheries de Moulinsart, Sanzot reste moins chère.

Ici, on a essayé toutes “*les* autres boucheries”, mais comme on fait “le tour *de*” quelque chose, on contracte le “*de les*” en “*des*”.

> J’ai essayé d’autres boucheries de Moulinsart, Sanzot reste moins chère.

Ici, on a essayé plusieurs autres boucheries, mais pas toutes. On a essayé “*des* boucheries“.

> J’ai fait le tour d’autres boucheries de Moulinsart, Sanzot reste moins chère.

Ici, on a à nouveau essayé ***des*** autres boucheries. Il s’avère que l’on fait toujours “le tour *de*” quelque chose, mais le **de** est absorbé par le **des** qui à son tour est contracté en **d’**